email html color images changes in dark mode
On mobile devices, if dark mode is enabled, the icons change color in a strange way:
on dark mode :

on light mode :

html code :
<div class="social">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://x.com/--myaccount-here--"><img alt="x" width="auto"
            height="auto" src="https://my-app-domin/images/social/twitter-x-line.png"></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/--myaccount-here--/"><img alt="instagram"
            width="auto" height="auto"
            src="https://my-app-domin/images/social/instagram-line.png"></a>
</div>

Note that the original pictures are white.

This should help ensure that your icons retain their original colors regardless of the device's dark mode settings.
    <style>
    .social img {
        filter: none;
        -webkit-filter: none;
    }
    
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
        .social img {
            filter: none;
        }
    }
</style>

<div class="social">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://x.com/--myaccount-here--"><img alt="x" width="auto"
            height="auto" src="https://my-app-domin/images/social/twitter-x-line.png"></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/--myaccount-here--/"><img alt="instagram"
            width="auto" height="auto"
            src="https://my-app-domin/images/social/instagram-line.png"></a>
</div>

This media query checks if the user has dark mode enabled and then applies the necessary styling to the icons.
